# Drawing a line between 2 vectors

Tags: rendering, godot, gdscript

I was trying to implement a simple mechanic by drawing a line between the sprite and the mouse, but it's not working that well:

[image: Screenshot showing red line emanating from a blue sprite]

```
extends KinematicBody2D
onready var player = $CollisionShape2D
var pos_two 
var pos
func _physics_process(delta):
    
    var vel = Vector2()
    pos_two = player.get_position()
    
    pos = get_global_mouse_position()
    look_at(pos)
    if Input.is_action_pressed("movethere"):
        vel = Vector2(400 , 0).rotated(rotation)
    vel = move_and_slide(vel)
func _draw():
    draw_line( pos_two ,pos, Color(255 , 0 , 0))
```

Comment: "it's not working that well" - in what specific way is the line being drawn differently than you wanted? From your screenshot, it looks like you have a line correctly drawn from the sprite to another point - presumably the mouse position? If it should be pointing somewhere else, you'll need to tell us this precisely, because we can only see what you've shown us.

Answer (score 0):

*To get it out of the way `Color` takes float in the range from `0.0` to `1.0`.*

---

Given that the code uses `_draw` but not calling `update` I believe that problem was that it was not updating every frame.

*Ah, but you see it move, don't you? I hear you, I'll get back to that.*

To make Godot call `_draw` again you had to add a call to `update` in `_process`.

---

The other issue are the coordinate systems.

- This is local space: `player.get_position()`
- This is global space: `get_global_mouse_position()`
- And this is local space again: `draw_line( pos_two ,pos, Color(255 , 0 , 0))`

*And this is why you see it move. When you rotate the body with `look_at(pos)` the local space changes. Also when you move the body with `move_and_slide`.*

Thus, first of all get the positions in global space:

```
pos_two = get_global_transform().origin
pos = get_global_mouse_position()
```

And second, convert them to local space to use them:

```
draw_line(to_local(pos_two), to_local(pos), Color(255 , 0 , 0))
```

Which gives you this code (I have added type information):

```
extends KinematicBody2D

onready var player:CollisionShape2D = $CollisionShape2D
var pos_two:Vector2
var pos:Vector2

func _physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    var vel := Vector2()
    pos_two = get_global_transform().origin
    pos = get_global_mouse_position()
    look_at(pos)
    if Input.is_action_pressed("movethere"):
        vel = Vector2(400 , 0).rotated(rotation)

    vel = move_and_slide(vel)
    update()

func _draw() -> void:
    draw_line(to_local(pos_two), to_local(pos), Color(1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

Why don't get the position in local space to begin with? Because you are changing the local space after you get the position and before you draw.

---

Thus, another option is to get the position when you are going to draw.

Do you know what is the position of the body in local space? That is right, it is at the origin. So we only need to figure out the position of the mouse pointer in local space.

The code is like this:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

onready var player:CollisionShape2D = $CollisionShape2D

func _physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    var vel := Vector2()
    look_at(get_global_mouse_position())
    if Input.is_action_pressed("movethere"):
        vel = Vector2(400 , 0).rotated(rotation)

    vel = move_and_slide(vel)
    update()

func _draw() -> void:
    draw_line(Vector2.ZERO, to_local(get_global_mouse_position()), Color(1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

---

*Yes,  I know I'm answering this years later.*